# Send/Broadcast audio data to shoutcast software iOS

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I have a use case, where a user can select a song from playlist and send it to stream on other iPhone devices(Multi casting).

I would like to know the work flow on how to send audio data to shoutcast software on server so that it acts as a radio station? and then on client side i can use Matt Gallagher Audio streamer(https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) to stream live audio.

Any help on the work flow or any sample codes are much appreciated.